# Obtaining full nUnit output in visual studio online

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have set up my VS 2013 environment to integrate with TFS in Visual Studio Online. I have configured a CI build to run and then run all my tests (nUnit framework) upon completion. However when the tests complete and I see the output it only says whether each test passed or failed, not the details of the assert statements I call in code, ie what error actually happened.

So it will say

GetPosMenus failed

But if I run the test locally in VS2013 I see the full error

```
GetPosMenus failed

Initialization method Data.Test.PosMenuDataRepositoryTests.LoadData threw exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Parameter name: index.
    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Testing.Shared.DataPopulation.Pos.PosMenuDataPopulator.LoadPosMenusIntoDatabase(IUnitOfWork work, IList`1 data, IList`1 venues) in PosMenuDataPopulator.cs: line 48
   at5 Data.Test.PosMenuDataRepositoryTests.LoadData() in PosMenuDataRepositoryTests.cs: line 50
```

How can I configure the online build engine to give me the full output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view this in your account in VSO online and within Visual Studio.

In VS:

Team Explorer Home -> Builds
Under All Build Definitions double-click the build definition you are interested in.
This should open a tab containing a history of completed builds. The default history is set to Today, you will need to change the Date Filter to see older builds. Note also that the visible build history will depend on the retention policy you have set in the build definition.

Double-click your build and you should see the following screen. Expand the test results and the exception should be visible

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can see it in VS, there aren't any nodes to expand in VS online but Ill manage with the IDE for now. In VS though it only says "showing 10 of 1048 failure(s)" and I can only look at error messages for 10 tests, the others it doesnt show. Is this configurable somewhere?

Comment: Never mind, that's just in the overview panel. If you click on the build link it then downloads the full results. Thanks!